# C++ Inheritance: Pass sub-class to a function expecting base-class and get sub-class behaviour

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

In the following toy example, I have a base class and a class which inherits from it. The child class overrides the method `doSomething()`. However when I pass an instance of the child class to a function expecting the base class, I get the behavior of the base class, i.e the output is `I'm the base class!` rather than `I'm the child class!`. How can I prevent this from happening and why does it happen (I guess there is some sort of implicit casting going on?).

Many thanks!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class BaseClass {
public:
    void doSomething() {
        cout << "I'm the base class!";
    }
};

class SubClass : public BaseClass {
public:
    void doSomething() {
        cout << "I'm a child class!";
    }
};

void thisFunction(BaseClass & instance) {
    instance.doSomething();
}

int main(int, char*[]) {
    SubClass sc;
    thisFunction(sc);
}
```

Comment: I recommend you [get a good C++ book or two to read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282), and read about *polymorphism* and **`virtual`** functions.

Comment: There's no such thing as "implicit casting". There's explicit and implicit *conversion*, and casting is explicit conversion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `BaseClass::doSomething()` is not virtual. This way, it can't be overridden, but only shadowed. Try changing its signature to

```
class BaseClass {
    virtual void doSomething() { /* ... */ }
};
```

No changes are required for the `SubClass`, it is, however, good practice to make use of the `override` keyword (your example code is a perfect illustration for this - marking the method with `override` makes the compiler complain if the exact same function signature isn't `virtual` in any base class) :

```
class SubClass : public BaseClass {
    void doSomething() override { /* ... */ }
};
```

In addition to that, please make the `BaseClass` destructor virtual, too (or `protected`), or you risk undefined behavior when deleting a `SubClass` instance through a `BaseClass` pointer.

Comment: Thank you, this works. More information (for those that want it) can be found here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/virtual-function-cpp/